# How to sort a character vector where elements contain numbers and letters in R?

Tags: r, arrays, database, data-science

My character array is the following:
**Note: the array was changed. Sorry, my mistake**

```
m <- c("VI-2005","III-2005","II-2005","I-2005","III-2006","II-2006","I-2006","VI-2006","IV-2007","III-2007","II-2007","I-2007")
```

I have roman numbers and years.
I would like to sort it in descending order so that I will have an output like this:

```
I-2005
II-2005
III-2005
IV-2005
I-2006
II-2006
III-2006
IV-2006
I-2007
II-2007
III-2007
IV-2007
```

I had try the `mixedsort` from the "gtools" package:

```
> # install.packages("gtools") ## Uncomment if not already installed
> library(gtools)
> mixedsort(m)
```

But it doesn't sort by the roman numbers.
Thank you for reading!

Comment: That's ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Split the input and transform the roman numerals into a factor:

```
library(data.table)
n <- tstrsplit(m, "-")
n[[1]] <- ordered(n[[1]], levels = c("I", "II", "III", "IV", 
                                    "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", 
                                    "IX", "X", "XI", "XII"))
n[[2]] <- as.integer(n[[2]])
n <- rev(n)

m[do.call(order, n)]
#[1] "I-2005"   "I-2005"   "II-2005"  "III-2005" "VI-2005"  "VI-2005"  "II-2006"  "III-2006"
#[9] "I-2007"   "II-2007"  "III-2007" "IV-2007"
```

**Edit:**

If you want to use this for plotting or modelling, turn `m` into an ordered factor:

```
library(data.table)
n <- tstrsplit(unique(m), "-")
n[[1]] <- ordered(n[[1]], levels = c("I", "II", "III", "IV", 
                                    "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", 
                                    "IX", "X", "XI", "XII"))
n[[2]] <- as.integer(n[[2]])
n <- rev(n)    

m <- ordered(m, levels = unique(m)[do.call(order, n)])
```

Comment: Well, then you should transform it into an actual `Date`. Good luck.

Comment: I am new coding in R. I really wanted to transform it as a ```Date```, I don't know how due to the roman numbers. The roman numbers represent each trimester of a year in my data base. I have a presentation tomorrow and I am going crazy. Any clue?

Comment: Well, if these are quarters, I wouldn't turn them into dates. See my edit.

Comment: I will try it! I also changed the array ```m```. See my edit.

Comment: It worked. I literally socked haha thank you! If I may ask, how do you learn to code in R?

Comment: Learning by doing. 10 years ago, I had a need for data analysis and took up R. Reading answers by more experienced users at Stackoverflow was helpful to me and answering questions myself helped me improve further. But ultimately, you need to invest time and effort, as always when you learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as.roman` to convert roman numerals to their type and then use `order` to order the dataframe.

```
data <- strcapture('(\\w+)-(\\d+)', m, 
                   proto = list(roman = character(), number = numeric()))
data$roman <- as.roman(data$roman)
data <- data[do.call(order, rev(data)), ]

#   roman number
#4      I   2005
#7      I   2005
#3     II   2005
#2    III   2005
#1     VI   2005
#8     VI   2005
#6     II   2006
#5    III   2006
#12     I   2007
#11    II   2007
#10   III   2007
#9     IV   2007
```

If you want the string back, you can paste it :

```
do.call(paste, c(data, sep = '-'))
# [1] "I-2005"   "I-2005"   "II-2005"  "III-2005" "VI-2005"  "VI-2005"  "II-2006" 
# [8] "III-2006" "I-2007"   "II-2007"  "III-2007" "IV-2007"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `as.roman` function. This will ensure a number 6 ie `VI` is before 9 ie `IX` when sorting

```
s <- read.table(text=m, sep="-")
with(s, do.call(paste, c(sep="-", s[order(V2, as.roman(V1)), ])))

 [1] "I-2005"   "I-2005"   "II-2005"  "III-2005" "VI-2005"  "VI-2005"  "II-2006"  "III-2006"
 [9] "I-2007"   "II-2007"  "III-2007" "IV-2007"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am working with a huge data base, but your code repeats some numbers ```[1] "I-2005"   "I-2005"   "I-2005"   "I-2005"   "II-2005"  "II-2005"  "II-2005" 
  [8] "II-2005"  "III-2005" "III-2005" "III-2005" "III-2005" "IV-2005"  "IV-2005"
  ``` The output is huge, but Stack overflow doesn't allow me to put all of it.

Comment: I want to graph it as a ```Date```, because each roman number represents a trimester of a year. I am new coding in R, I am going nutz, do you have any idea?

Comment: @Victory the repetition is due to the fact that your data contains duplicates. You will realize that the length of the results is equal to the length of the original vector